# Which format is each module in in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, object

In Node.js, each module is in an object format that has the following properties:

```
Module {
  id: '.',
  exports: {},
  parent: null,
  filename: 'C:\\Users\\Node\\first-app\\app.js',
  loaded: false,
  children: [],
  paths:
   [ 'C:\\Users\\app\\node_modules',
     'C:\\Users\\\\Node\\node_modules',
     'C:\\Users\\node_modules',
     'C:\\Users\\Documents\\node_modules',
     'C:\\Users\\node_modules',
     'C:\\Users\\node_modules',
     'C:\\node_modules' ] }
```

But, each module is also in a function format as such:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { 
//content of the function
})
```

where the function takes exports, require, module, __filename, and __dirname as its parameters.  The former is in a key/value format and the latter is in a function definition format. Which one is it?

Comment: "*each module is also in a function format*" - uh, no? That's just an IIFE that will initialise the module object, nothing more. The function isn't kept around, it doesn't represent the module.

Comment: I think the function is always there because whenever there is a syntax error, the function such as Function.Module._load and Function.Module.runMain are invoked, no?

Comment: The function is created once when the module is loaded, then it is invoked to evaluate the module source, but then it is discarded. The module refers only to the module object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code examples are of two different but related things. The first is the module object, which is described [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_object). The second is something that nodes does internally: wrapping a module in an anonymous function, which among other things, helps keep top level variables in your module scoped to that module rather than exposing them globally. This module wrapping behavior is described [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper).